# fopen function in C + write into file

Tags: c, debugging, fopen, fwrite

I want to write some data into a file. But I have too many data and each one should be named through a certain structure depending on the number of nodes and number of edges each data file has.

For example: for a data having 10 nodes and 20 edges, its name will be `s_10_20.txt`
for a data having 14 nodes and 30 edges, its name will be `s_14_30.txt`
the structure I'm following is: `s_numOfNodes_numOfEdges.txt`
**(knowing that `numOfNodes` and `numOfEdges` are already scanned from the data file.)**

The code I wrote is:

```
FILE *fp;
fp=fopen("s_%d_%d.txt",numOfNodes,numOfEdges,"w+");
```

This is giving me the following errors:

1. passing argument 2 of fopen makes pointer from integer without a cast
2. too many arguments to function fopen

How can I write it in any other way?

Comment: Why are you assuming that `fopen()` takes a format string whereas it doesn't? Read its documentation. Understand that string formatting is not magic, it doesn't happen automatically when you hammer percent signs into your string literals (C is not Python!), and then use `snprintf()` to construct the appropriate filename.

Comment: @Dayalrai No cplusplus.com please. Firstly because this is C, not C++, secondly because cplusplus.com contains serious errors and a lot of misinformation. [Here's](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fopen.html) the official documentation for `fopen()`.

Comment: ooppss accept my apology :(

Comment: H2CO3, how do I use snprintf() ? Can you please help me cause I'm a beginner in programming.

Comment: @SabineKhalil What have you tried so far to use it?

Comment: I used fopen to write it into a file of determined format but I need to change this format as I mentioned in the question so that it matches every single data file and not only be a single known determined file name. @H2CO3 
how can snprintf() help here?

Comment: @SabineKhalil It lets you construct your file name properly. So, have you read its documentation?

Comment: @H2CO3 yes I did. will the code become the following: 
FILE *fp;
fp=fopen("s_a_b.txt","w+");
snprintf("s_%d_%d.txt",a,b); where a and b are specified to be the variables that i want.
What is wrong with this code? thank you!

Comment: @SabineKhalil Well, it doesn't really seem so, sorry to say. You have to allocate a buffer for the filename, then `snprintf()` the actual filename into that buffer, then `FILE *fp = fopen(buffer, "w+");` to pass the appropriate filename to `fopen()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sprintf` function can help you.

```
char file_name[MAX_PATH];
sprintf(file_name, s_%d_%d.txt",numOfNodes, numOfEdges);
fopen(file_name, "w+");
```

Comment: What do you mean with MAX_PATH... im getting an error that it is undeclared! how do i declare it? thank you!

Comment: @SabineKhalil：MAX_PATH means the maximum characters of your file name.you can just #define MAX_PATH 255 or so.